# FFMPEG Channel Mapping

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a 24 bit WAV file that consists of 8 channels. What I need to do is convert it into 4 24 bit two channel files where the output wavs are made up of source channels (1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8).

Anyone have any thoughts of the best way to do that using FFmpeg?

Comment: The reason for closing as "not a real question" doesn't seem right. The question is perfectly clear. However, it might not belong in stackoverflow, and should be moved to another stackexchange site? I'm not sure which.

Answer (score 2):

See -map and map_channel from the [ffmpeg docs](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options):

> ‘-map
>   [-]input_file_id[:stream_specifier][,sync_file_id[:stream_specifier]]
>   | [linklabel] (output)’
>
> Designate one or more input streams as a source for the output file.
>   Each input stream is identified by the input file index input_file_id
>   and the input stream index input_stream_id within the input file. Both
>   indices start at 0. If specified, sync_file_id:stream_specifier sets
>   which input stream is used as a presentation sync reference.
>
> The first -map option on the command line specifies the source for
>   output stream 0, the second -map option specifies the source for
>   output stream 1, etc.
>
> A - character before the stream identifier creates a "negative"
>   mapping. It disables matching streams from already created mappings.
>
> An alternative [linklabel] form will map outputs from complex filter
>   graphs (see the ‘-filter_complex’ option) to the output file.
>   linklabel must correspond to a defined output link label in the graph.

and map_channel:

> ‘-map_channel
>   [input_file_id.stream_specifier.channel_id|-1][:output_file_id.stream_specifier]’
>
> Map an audio channel from a given input to an output. If
>   output_file_id.stream_specifier is not set, the audio channel will be
>   mapped on all the audio streams.
>
> Using "-1" instead of input_file_id.stream_specifier.channel_id will
>   map a muted channel.